# Reading XML with C# and grouping Information together

Tags: c#, xml, linq, linq-to-xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
<detail id="TestXML">
  <styles>
    <Maininfo id="Set1">
      <info1>Test1</info1>
      <info2>Test2</info2>
      <info2>Test3</info2>
      <secondinfo>
        <secondinfo-base id="1234567">
          <description>BlahBlah</description>
          <quantity>1</quantity>
        </secondinfo-base>
      </secondinfo>
      <colors>
        <color id="54321">
          <color-id>54321</color-id>
          <name>Test Color</name>
        </color>
      </colors>
    </Maininfo>
    </styles>
    <styles>
    <Maininfo id="Set2">
      <info1>Test4</info1>
      <info2>Test5</info2>
      <info2>Test6</info2>
      <secondinfo>
        <secondinfo-base id="7654321">
          <description>BlahBlahandBlah</description>
          <quantity>2</quantity>
        </secondinfo-base>
      </secondinfo>
      <colors>
        <color id="12345">
          <color-id>12345</color-id>
          <name>Yellow</name>
        </color>
        <color id="23456">
          <color-id>23456</color-id>
          <name>Green</name>
        </color>
        <color id="34567">
          <color-id>34567</color-id>
          <name>Red</name>
        </color>
      </colors>
    </Maininfo>
    </styles>   
</detail>
```

I'm trying to build a file that has each of the color ids and names grouped together with the info1, info2, info3 fields.  For example, I need to manage to come up with 4 different groups with this information.

- Group 1 = Set 1, Test1, Test2, Test3, 1234567, 54321, Test Color
- Group 2 = Set 2, Test4, Test5, Test6, 7654321, 12345, Yellow
- Group 3 = Set 2, Test4, Test5, Test6, 7654321, 23456, Green
- Group 4 = Set 2, Test4, Test5, Test6, 7654321, 34567, Red

I can get the colors and everything, but I cant seem to get the information preceding it.

This is what I was doing to get the colors and color id.

```
        var xml = Xdocument.Load("test.xml");
        var color = from c in xml.Root.Descendants("color")
                            select new{
                            colorNumber = (string)c.Element("color-id"),
                            colorName = (string)c.Element("name"),
                            };
```

I've tried so many different ways to getting the information that would pair with it, but I just can't figure it out.  I hope I explained this well enough.

I have looked around quite a bit on this site for something similar to what I'm asking, but I can't find anything.  Can someone please help?

It was hard thinking of a subject for this problem. Sorry if it was misleading.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understood what you need correctly, something like this should work for your example. You can use the `Parent` property of the `color` elements you find to go traverse back up the tree and pair it with the other information you want.

```
var colorGroups = xml
    .Descendants("color")
    .Select(colorElement => 
    {
        XElement mainInfo = colorElement.Parent.Parent;

        return new
        {
            Set = mainInfo.Attribute("id").Value,
            Color = colorElement.Element("name").Value,
            Id = colorElement.Element("color-id").Value,
            SecondInfo = mainInfo.Element("secondinfo").Elements("secondinfo-base").Select(b => b.Attribute("id").Value).ToList(),
            Infos = mainInfo.Elements().Where(b => b.Name.LocalName.StartsWith("info")).Select(b => b.Value).ToList()
        };
    });
```

This produces an enumerable of dynamically typed objects. To access this information you could do, for example,

```
foreach (var colorGroup in colorGroups)
{
    Console.WriteLine(colorGroup.Set);
}
```

As they're dynamically typed, you won't have intelli-sense for the property names in Visual Studio, but it'll still compile and work at runtime. I returned dynamic objects to follow your original code, but you can use a real class here instead (personally I would prefer this, infact I might be tempted to deserialize the whole lot into a set of objects since it seems you're using most of the information anyway and it'd be easier to work with and more readable, but it's more than I want to get into here).

Comment: This helps. I didn't realize I could do Parent.Parent. I have a version that kind of works now because of that.  I say kind of because I ran into an xml file that has multiple "secondinfo-base" entries, and I can only get the first entry to show up. Also, this may be a dumb question, but how do you access the information pulled with your code?

Comment: @Matt, see edit, this should handle the multiple `secondinfo-base` elements. I've given an example of how you can pull info out of that result grouping.

Comment: I see.  Thanks a lot. This helps greatly.